# TortoiseSVN merge option missing from tools

Tags: tortoisesvn

I recently upgraded to TortoiseSVN 1.8.10 and I no longer have the option to merge.  Has anyone else ever experienced this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You right-clicked something that is not a SVN working copy, but a plain old folder. Try with an existing working copy, or make one first.

Latest version of TortoiseSVN as of this moment is 1.14.1. If you are positive that you right-clicked a working copy, one possible reason would be that you downgraded TortoiseSVN instead of upgrading, and the old version does not recognize a working copy made in a more recent version.